# Render Item in Agenda using database data - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm trying to show the items I get from my database in the calendar, everything is working fine (maybe not), but in short I got the data from the database with an array and then I converted it to an object (because the calendar only accepts objects), but it doesn't show anything and it doesn't give an error either

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { LocaleConfig, Agenda } from 'react-native-calendars'
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';

import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, set, push, get, child } from 'firebase/database';


const Calendario = () => {
 const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
 const data = []
 var obj = {}

// getting data from the database

  useEffect(() => {
    getInDB()
  } ,[])

  const getInDB = () => {
    get(child(dbRef, 'users/' + app.currentUser.uid)).then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(childsnap => {
          let dateD = childsnap.child("date").val()
          let titleD = childsnap.child("title").val()
          let dtsD = childsnap.child("details").val()

          // "yyyy-MM-dd": [{any: "whatever", any2: "whatever"}],
          data.push({
            [dateD] : [{ title: titleD, details: dtsD }],
          });

        })
        obj = Object.assign({}, ...data)
        console.log(obj)
    })
  }

  const renderItem = (item) => {
    return(
        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.textInf}>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textInf}>{item.details}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }

 return (
  <>
   <Agenda
   items={obj}
   renderEmptyDate={() => {
    return <View />;
   }}
   renderEmptyData={() => {
    return <View />;
   }}
   selected={new Date()}
   minDate={null}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   markingType="custom"
   />
  </>
}
```

Comment: Where is `obj` coming from? Is this a state? You need to set a state that holds your data and provide that state to the `items` prop. The assignment of `obj`, as it currently is, will not trigger a rerender.

Comment: @DavidScholz I just created a empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use state and set it or otherwise your component will not be rerendered with the new data.

Furthermore, the `Agenda` component expects an object. By using `data` as an array and the spread operator, we won't get the desired result.

You can implement this correctly as follows.

```js
...
const [obj, setObj] = useState({});
...

const getInDB = () => {
    get(child(dbRef, 'users/' + app.currentUser.uid)).then((snapshot) => {
        const temp = {}
        snapshot.forEach(childsnap => {
          let dateD = childsnap.child("date").val()
          let titleD = childsnap.child("title").val()
          let dtsD = childsnap.child("details").val()

          Object.assign(temp, {dateD: [{ title: titleD, details: dtsD }]})

        })
        setObj(temp)
    })
  }
```

I have [implemented a little snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/react-native-calendars-example).

Comment: Now its generating some keys like this:

Object {
  "0": Object {
    "2022-08-05": Array [
      Object {
        "details": "teste",
        "title": "teste",
      },
    ],
  }
}

Comment: It still doesn't show anything

Comment: Could you hardcode the `items` in `Agenda` to `items={{'2022-08-22': [{title: 'Test'}]}}` and tell me if this item is visible?

Comment: This mark the date but does not show the name, I think the problem is in the renderItem

Comment: Pardon, I mean `title`.

Comment: I know, i changed to title and changed in render to name and still not showing anything, but mark the date

Comment: If you use `setObj(Object.Assign({}, ...data))`, does it mark all data?

Comment: No, after using useState a date is being marked, but is just one

Comment: would you like the whole code and move to a chat?

Comment: Yes, let's do it.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation

Comment: I was able to show all dates by copying the array to a let object and using Object.assign, but tour code is more optimized i think, thanks. But still not showing the title and description, it is marking all dates

Comment: I managed to make the renderItem show the title and description, the problem was that I was trying to implement purecomponent and I must have done something wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: Uff nice, I was running out of ideas. Your welcome!